# What can I use, beside applesauce, to replace fat in baking?

Tags: baking, substitutions

Due to dietary restrictions, I can not have apples, or any byproduct.  There are lots of recipes that use applesauce to replace fat, but what can I substitute for applesauce in these recipes?

Answer (score 9):

You could replace the applesauce with the fat that it was originally replacing.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would choose recipes that don't include apples. There is something just *silly* about substituting for an ingredient that is a substitution to begin with (I was one of the upvotes for replacing applesauce with the fat it was it was originally replacing). However, if you have a particular recipe that you love with applesauce and you want to keep it as similar as possible, you might try pear butter. Google "pear butter recipe" for ideas. Keep your seasonings similar to the applesauce you've liked in the past. Since pectin is the key to applesauce "working" as a fat replacement, and pears have even more pectin than apples, it should be a pretty good substitute.

Comment: In this context, its not about seasonings or flavor, its about the ability to create the proper texture in quick breads in lieu of the fats.  Mild or absent flavor is the goal.

Comment: Exactly. Pear butter recipes tend to be highly seasoned.